# Macos: ping: sendto: Socket is not connected

Tags: macos, sockets, tcp, ping, icmp

Using ping on Macos [Big Sur 11.01], I'm getting this error message:

```
ping: sendto: Socket is not connected
```

What is likely to be the problem? What can I do to prevent it?

The call from bash is:

```
ping -t2 -c1 time.com
```

Comment: I've changed the tags around because this doesn't seem to have much to do with the bash shell nor UDP.  ping uses ICMP rather than UDP, and I'd assume you'd get the same behaviour if ping was invoked from another shell/program

Comment: Great, thank you! I was, actually, just going to give the ping, but I thought I'd mention bash in case anybody thought that relevant.